# How get two label in QuerySelectField - Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I want to use the first and last name in the user selection.

```
    def user_query():
        return User.query
    
    class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
        id          = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        firstname   = db.Column(db.String(20))
        lastname    = db.Column(db.String(20))

class task_add(FlaskForm):        
        user_responsible = QuerySelectField("responsible", query_factory=user_query, allow_blank=True, get_label='firstname')
```

In attribute get_label is it possible to have just one column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tbink column property is what you need. Add this to your user model and filter on fullname. See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_columns.html#using-column-property-for-column-level-options.

```
fullname = column_property(firstname + " " + lastname)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
user_responsible = QuerySelectField("responsible", query_factory=user_query, allow_blank=True, get_label=lambda s: '%s %s' % (s.firstname, s.lastname))
```

is what you need.